# Running Clojure project in Cursive

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, cursive

I'm trying to run a short Clojure program in IntelliJ\Cursive. 
My program includes two files:

**project.clj:**

```
(defproject try3 "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]]
  :main try3.core)
```

and:

**core.clj:**

```
(ns try3.core)

(defn foo
  "I don't do a whole lot."
  [x]
  (println x "Hello, World!"))

(defn -main [] (println "hi"))
```

I want that when I run the project, the -main function will run automatically. What do I have to do to make this happen?

Comment: Have you checked [this page](https://cursive-ide.com/userguide/repl.html)?  Your code looks ok.  Fire up leiningen and `lein run` your project.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the Run configuration in IntelliJ to get the program to print the Hello World string.
Open Run > Edit Configuraitons...
Add the test program if not done and make sure the configuration has the Run -main from Clojure namespace enabled.

[image: IntelliJ screenshot]

Comment: I wonder why this has to be done manually for every single project. It's only natural to assume people will want to run their projects. Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe you know this already: Ctrl-Shift-R runs the currently open file. If your file has a main, there should be a green arrow next to it to conveniently run it. This will also create a temp run configuration that then can be saved. Right-click in the project navigation bar on the file will present some run options.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to create run configuration in IDEA. Also, `-main` method tells that you probably try to create runnable class. In order to achieve that you need to modify your namespace declaration:

```
(ns try3.core
  (:gen-class))
; note :gen-class above. It tells clojure that file is intended to 
; be compiled into class instead of be running as a script.
```

Then you need to create IDEA run configuration of *Application* type. Specify your namespace as main class. Take a look to the screenshot and comments in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/cursiveide/status/463675141063335937). Also you may need to modify "Compiler" > "Clojure Compiler" settings and set "Compile all Clojure namespaces" there. After these steps you should have runnable configuration.